# How to use sqlite database for repeated calls

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

In my project i need to call the sqlite database on constant basis. I got the database locked error which i kind of solved by giving sqlite timeout for 500ms. Stil sometimes i get the error. Is there any way not to lock the database error.?

Comment: Increase the timeout to at least 50 s.

Comment: I get memory spikes then...and app hangs.

Comment: Then you have to find out what other connection is accessing the DB, and why.